# Program can't reach a certain part of code

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I'm not sure at all why my code is doing this. In the below code snippet, it never reaches the bottom part of code (the printf statement along with the 3 frees and the return of -1). Even if I give it an invalid input, it will still run until it has searched all parts of the array, and then just quits out like there's no problem.

```
int findtargetline(char* targ, char* filename, int count, char** depend) {
    char* line = malloc(160*sizeof(char));
    char* buffer = malloc(16);
    FILE* fil = file_open(filename);
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (depend[i] == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR: MISSING DEPENDENCY DATA STRUCTURE");
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            strcpy(line, depend[i]);
            line = line + strspn(line, delims);
            sscanf(line, "%s ", buffer);

            if (strcmp(buffer, targ) == 0) {
                free(line);
                free(buffer);
                fclose(fil);
                printf("%s, and %d\n", targ, i);
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("wtf");

    free(line);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(fil);
    return -1;
}
```

I feel like the answer should be super easy, yet I'm not seeing it. Anyone know why? D:

Comment: Try correctly indenting your code

Comment: You should begin by fixing this: `line = line + ...`, since you cannot `free(line)` afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean by "quits out like there's no problem"? In the future, you should post a [minimal compilable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe what you are seeing in more detail (including any error code, if appropriate).

Comment: well the answer is simple .I dont really know what are you trying to achieve , but u have 2x `returns` in your function and with the fact it never reaches the bottom part of it -> it means 1 of those `return`s are triggered every time u run it.

Comment: It just continues on, like it never existed. If I put in a print statement somewhere right after I call findtargetline that calls for the invalid target, it'll finally reach the end of the file that I'm trying to get it to reach. Otherwise just no errors, nothing, it's like the input just disappears.

Comment: in addition , I dont think you even want to use those returns , since u r allocating memory when you are just in the function , at its first lines , and if u have so bad input or etc you call `return` which means you will never free your memory at all .

Comment: And Roma-MT, I've actually tried removing the returns and moved them to the bottom, but then NONE of my inputs ever reach them, it just runs through it and does seemingly nothing.

Comment: Well this is your logical mistakes already . 
if you want to do it , you just need to save what you want to return in some int variable , and when u reach the end return your int . 

I just tell you , if your function run flow reached return it exits the function instantly and will never reach its end.

Comment: Are you sure that all strings pointed by `depend` are nul terminated?

Comment: I have tried that Roma, I set defined an integer (lets say index), and then inside the second if statement I set index to i. I moved the return down to the bottom. But when I did that, it never reached the return statement or free statements. It just never ended.

Edit: actually this time, I put a break statement in the second if statement, and made a third statement checking to see if i reached it's final value or if it was successfully found. This time it worked, not sure why but at least it does. Thank you!

Comment: You don't seem to actually be doing anything with `fil`?

Comment: cklin you're probably right, there was a lot of other code that's been slowly being pruned. Still in the process, didn't catch that! Thanks for the pointer :D

Comment: and what about first if statement ? I think it is the 1 who exits from your function .
for suggestion you better use `continue` there instead of `return` then u will reach the end.

Comment: Also, where is `delims` declared and initialized?  If it isn't initialized somewhere, then `strspn` probably returns 0, which causes your whole `line` to be copied to `buffer`.  This might cause `strcmp` to always evaluate to true, leading to the `return i` to happen on each call.  Just a possibility.

Comment: It is probably never reaching the bottom of the function because it is returning at one of the two returns inside your for loop. Have you tried debugging your code step by step to see what is going on exactly?

Comment: Set `breakpoints` at the two `returns` in the `for` loop.  It is safe to assume that you are hitting one of those 2 `returns` and this is why you never reach the one outside of the `for` loop

Comment: Do you need to print a newline after `"wtf"` and after the error message to flush the output buffer? You also might want to get rid of fil` and of `line` (you don't really need a temporary allocated string here, you can work directly with pointers into `depend[i]`) and make `buffer` an array on the stack, i.e. `char buffer[16]`. That will save you a _lot_ of housekeeping.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect when you call the function with a count of 0?

You don't? Why didn't you tell us?